# react-navigation v4 не реагирует на системную кнопку back Android, androidX

Tags: android, react-native

Использую подобный код:

```
export const navStack = (screenName) => createStackNavigator({
    Screen1,
    Screen2,
    Screen3
}, {
    initialRouteName: screenName,
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
        headerStyleInterpolator: HeaderStyleInterpolators.forUIKit,
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true
    }
});

const AppTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    TabScreen1: {
        screen: navStack("Screen1")
    },
    TabScreen2: {
        screen: AnyScreen
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: "TabScreen1",
    backBehavior: "none",
    tabBarOptions: {
        showLabel: false
    }
});

export const App = createAppContainer(AppTabNavigator);
```

Следующий код реагирует на свайпы, но при нажатии на системную кнопку назад на Android нет никакого эффекта. Как можно добавить реагирование на системную кнопку назад?

Comment: _`backBehavior: "none",`_ не смущает?

Comment: убрал, результат тот же. Не работает(